# Deploying angular 2 App (angular cli) to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, angular, web-deployment, angular-cli

I built and angular 2 app with angular cli
ng build command works totally fine, it creates the dist folder.

In order to deploy it I followed this tutorial
[Deploy angular 2 app to heroku](https://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-cli-webpack-project-heroku/)

When I follow all the steps,  I type `heroku open` but I get an app error

`ng: not found`

log

[image]

here is my package.json file if you want to see it

It seems that is problem of angular-cli and his command ng
but here in my package.json i have it

```
`{
  "name": "rusticstock",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g http-server",
    "postinstall": "ng build && mv dist/* ."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/common": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",`enter code here`
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.6.0",
    "npm": "3.10.3"
  }
}
`
```

One more thing, when I'm deploying I see installing components like @angular/common ... but no all of them.

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: it seems for some reason angular cli was not installed in server.

Comment: I don't understand why!! If I have it in my package.json

Answer (score -6, accepted):

My problem was that I was working in another branch and heroku only was taking the progress made in the master branch

Comment: Hi @Rodrigo Espinel, maybe you're right in using the wrong branch, but all those downvotes show that this answer is wrong. Maybe your other branch is defining something that makes it work (like the solution from @abhiesingh). Would you please remove your answer, not to confuse users having the same problem?

Answer (score 7):

looks like your heroku app instance does not have angular-cli installed.
I found a way to get it installed.

In your package JSON, add preinstall command like this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g angular-cli",
    "postinstall": "ng build && mv dist/* ."
  },
```

This will get angular-cli installed on heroku server and you will not get ng command not found related errors.

Answer (score 0):

While "git push heroku master" is going on, heroku runs the package.json file. 
By default, however, Heroku will only install the packages listed in the dependencies object and will ignore those in devDependencies. Since we want the application build step to take place on the server rather than on our local machine, we need to adjust the package.json file a bit.

Angular CLI apps put the @angular/cli module itself as a dev dependency, meaning that we won't be able to access any ng commands on the server. To get around this, we need to move it to dependencies.

```
 // package.json
 "dependencies": {
 // ...
   "@angular/cli": "7.3.9",
 },
```

Comment: This won't work. Other dependencies such as "@angular-devkit/build-angular" are also required. The best way is to add a pre-install command as answered by @abhiesingh.